# If statement, comparing values with =

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement

Is this if statement correct?

```
if ($row->totMED="0" or $row->MEDC="0"){
  $avgMed='N/A';
} 
else {
  $avgMed='Medical: $'.($row->totMED / $row->MEDC);
}
```

Comment: testing for equality is `==`. assigning a value is `=`.

Comment: A single = assigns a value! use a double == for comparison

Comment: I cannot comment on your mental state without additional information.

Comment: "No" and "We're not licensed to make that determination"

Comment: Thank you guys so much, been coding all day, dunno how I missed that. Guess it's break time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for: `$row->totMED == "0"` or `$row->totMED === "0"`

### Loose equality

`==` is loose equality, meaning that the compared values are similar in value. For example, all of these statements are true:

```
0 == false //true because 0 is like nothing
"" == false //true because an empty string is like nothing
1 == true //true because 1 is something
```

`"abc" == true` *might* be true depending on...things. In php it's true at the moment and in javascript it isn't. That's the problem with loose equality. The checking process can be complicated and the result can be unexpected. Strict equality is good.

### Strict equality

`===`, or strict equality, means same in value AND type. All of these are true:

```
1 === 1
true === true
'abc' === 'abc'
```

and these are false:

```
1 === "1" // first value is integer and second is a string
true === "true" //first value is a boolean and second is a string
```

### Basic assignment operator

A single `=` is an assignment operator, which sets the variable on the left to the value on the right. When you use `=`, you're setting the value of the variable, not comparing two values.

`$row->totMED = "0"` means that `$row->totMED` now has a value of "0".

Comment: Why should it be lower-case? Language constructs are not case-sensitive. See [demo](http://3v4l.org/SPvUC). (although using lower-case version would be better, IMO).

Comment: Keywords are case-insensitive in PHP.  Lowercase is generally preferred, but not required.

Comment: Oops, removed that. I honestly never tried it, but I've never seen it that way either :)

Comment: This answer would be pretty much complete if an explanation were included about why the OP's code doesn't error out, and what it's actually doing.

Comment: @cHao oops, sorry I was tied up. Working on that.